# How to make shorter alias (shorthand) of 127.0.0.1 to simplify typing?

Tags: localhost

On my localhost, i type tens of times every day,

```
localhost/mysite
```

or recently (per recomendations), swiched directly to local ip:

```
127.0.0.1/mysite
```

however, is there any method that I could make it shorter for typing? like I set `1` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

```
1/mysite
```

I have tried aliasing in `hosts.etc` but seems it doesnt work with numbers like that.

Comment: Does it have to be a number? `l` is just as short. You could try `::1` (IPv6) as well.

Comment: @gronostaj you could post that as answer. Yes, at first I did that, but as my mind firstly comes to `1...` the number could have been better for me, but seems i have to switch to lowercase L: `l`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be at least three ways to shorten this:

1. Use 127.1 (which is shorthand for 127.0.0.1)
2. Use ::1 (localhost in IPv6)
3. Create an entry in /etc/hosts. You seem to have already tried that, but that should work.

Note that a webserver does look at the hostname used (unlike most other protocols). If you use an IP then the webserver might be configured to show a different website than as if you used a hostname.

Answer (score 5):

"0" as in ssh 0 or telnet 0

0 - on Linux system at least - means "an IP address of this machine", and if I understand correctly, it synonymous with `hostname`